# How to express this expression in a compact way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

it is my second question. I have the following expression:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{K} a_i^j X_i^T X_i b_j$

Where matrix $a$ has dimensions $n*k$, matrix $X$ is $n*d$ and matrix $b$ is $d*k$; the result should have dimensionality $d*1$.

I only obtain:

$\sum_{j=1}^{K} X^T S_j(a) X b_j$,

With $S_j(a)$ is a diagonal matrix generated from the $j$-th column of matrix $a$ and has dimensions $n*n$.

I want to know if there is a more compact (or elegant) expression. I tried combining $a,X,b$ but I am unable to find it.

Thanks!!

Mark

Comment: Shouldn't it be $X^TX$ instead of $X_i^TX_i$?

Comment: I don't think so. $X_i$ has dimensions $1*d$ and $b_j$ has dimensions $d*1$. The summation over $i$ generates an operation over $X$.

Comment: My question is : what is $X_i$?

Comment: Hi!, $X$ is a feature matrix with $n$ records and $d$ dimensions. $X_i$ is the $i$ row and has dimensionality $1*d$.

Comment: Are you sure in your first expression that it is $X^T_iX_i$ and not $X^T_iX_j$ with a $j$ instead of a $i$ for the second vector ?